# JavaScript check for multiple undefined objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

the value for the database variable is 0, that is -----> Number(0). So this is falsy. Therefore !0 seems to return true.

I have this code block

```
if(!(port && host && database)){
        throw new Error('one was undefined');
    }
```

for some reason, this JS code is throwing an error when it shouldn't and that seems to be because the database variable has the value 0. I assume the above code block is equivalent to:

```
if(!port || !host || !database){
      throw new Error('one was undefined');
  }
```

?

*Given a value like 0 or 1, or another truthy/falsy value is there a way to create shorthand code to check that at least one value of many is defined?*

Comment: Are you trying to test whether the variable's value is `undefined`, or when the variable's value hasn't actually been defined?

Comment: the problem is that the value for database is '0'...this is falsy, so ! seems to return true in that case, which messes this up.

Comment: @dsg: No, && is correct.

Comment: Is the value `0` or `'0'`? `'0'` is truthy. In any case, consider doing a more specific check of the variable's value than just whether it's truthy, such as `database === the_specific_thing_i_dont_want_it_to_be`.

Comment: @dsg That's actually correct. [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Try `!!` instead of `!`

Comment: !! interesting....thanks

Comment: @silentw: Why would you do that? That would only throw the error if all 3 values were truthy.

Comment: @user2357112 `!(!!port && !!host && !!database)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What about something like this?**

```
function isDef(v) {
    return v !== undefined && v !== null;
} 

if(!(isDef(port) && isDef(host) && isDef(database))){
    throw new Error('one was undefined');
}
```

If your variable is `undefined` or `null`, then it considers it 'undefined', else it is defined, even if its value is `0`.

**Or you could make a function that takes multiple variables as arguments and checks whether they all are defined or not:**

```
function allDef() {
    for(var i = arguments.length; i--;) {
        if(arguments[i] === undefined || arguments[i] === null) 
            return false;
    }
    return arguments.length > 0 ? true : false;
}

if(!allDef(port, host, database)) {
    throw new Error('One was undefined');
}
```

Comment: That `isDef` function could just be written as `return v !== undefined`.